# Painting an ellipse that fits a row of node but is not narrow and long

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit

I want to draw a Tikz diagram, in which an ellipse contains a row of smaller ellipses.  I tried doing so using the fitting library:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={inner sep=1pt},
  proc/.style={shape=ellipse, draw}
]
\path node[proc] (q) {q} -- ++(2cm,0) 
      node[proc] (p1) {p$_1$} -- ++(1.5cm,0)
      node (d) {\ldots} -- ++(1.5cm,0)
      node[proc] (pn) {p$_n$};
\node[fit=(q)(p1)(d)(pn), proc] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result is a long and narrow ellipse:

[image: bad ellipse]

I would prefer the surrounding ellipse to be shorter and taller, i.e., end closer to the `q` and `pn` nodes, and also have slightly more height.  What is the right configuration for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My original answer is below the line. Here's a slightly improved version, which uses two "strategically-placed" pegs to distort the ellipse. I think this approach will need less manual fine tuning (of `envel/inner sep` and `peg/node distance`).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={inner sep=1pt},
  proc/.style={shape=ellipse, draw},
  peg/.style={draw=none,color=black!0,node distance=1cm},
  envel/.style={shape=ellipse, draw, inner sep=-0.5cm}
]
\path node[proc] (q) {q} -- ++(2cm,0) 
      node[proc] (p1) {p$_1$} -- ++(1.5cm,0)
      node (d) {\ldots} -- ++(1.5cm,0)
      node[proc] (pn) {p$_n$};
\node  [peg,above of=p1] (c1) {+}; 
\node  [peg,below of=d] (c2) {+};
\node[fit=(q)(p1)(d)(pn)(c1)(c2), envel] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

Here's a slightly exaggerated answer. I suggest you play with the `envel` construction's `inner sep` and `minimum height` parameters to find what suits you best.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={inner sep=1pt},
  proc/.style={shape=ellipse, draw},
  envel/.style={shape=ellipse, draw, inner sep=-0.5cm, minimum height=4.5cm}
]
\path node[proc] (q) {q} -- ++(2cm,0) 
      node[proc] (p1) {p$_1$} -- ++(1.5cm,0)
      node (d) {\ldots} -- ++(1.5cm,0)
      node[proc] (pn) {p$_n$};
\node[fit=(q)(p1)(d)(pn), envel] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: @Little Bobby Tables If an answer is good enough to accept, it's good enough to upvote...

Comment: @Seamus; @Little Bobby Tables: Thank you both... (:-)

Answer (score 26):

Here's the "proper" way to do it: Adjust the `ellipse` shape. As it is, the circumscribing ellipse has the same height to width ratio `H/W` as the rectangle of nodes it circumscribes (`A/B`). In this case, `H=sqrt(2)*A` and `B=sqrt(2)*W`. This, of course, doesn't have to be that way. To get other aspect ratios that circumscribe a rectangle, you can scale the ratio using a factor `c`. The height and width of the ellipse then become `H=sqrt(c^2+1)*A` and `W=sqrt(c^2+1)/c*B`.

The code below declares a new shape called `newellipse` that will circumscribe a rectangle (or a set of nodes) just like the standard ellipse, but you can scale its height to width ratio using the key `ellipse ratio`. The code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={draw},
  every newellipse node/.style={inner sep=0pt}
]
\path node (a) {A} -- ++(2cm,0) node (b) {B};
\node[fit=(a)(b), newellipse] {};
\node[fit=(a)(b), red, newellipse, ellipse ratio=2] {};
\node[fit=(a)(b), blue, newellipse, ellipse ratio=6] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

then yields

[image: new ellipse with scale ratio]

Here's the complete code. Only three lines are changed compared to the original `ellipse` shape, but unfortunately the whole `\radius` command has to be repeated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}


\makeatletter

\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd,
    ellipse ratio/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgf/ellipse ratio}{#1}},
    ellipse ratio/.initial=1
}

\pgfdeclareshape{newellipse}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=ellipse]
  \inheritanchorborder[from=ellipse]
  \savedanchor\radius{%
    % 
    % Caculate ``height radius''
    % 
    \pgf@y=.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}%
    \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yb%
    % 
    % Caculate ``width radius''
    % 
    \pgf@x=.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}%
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xb%
    % 
    % Adjust
    %
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgf/ellipse ratio}{\ratioscale}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\widthfactor{sqrt(\ratioscale^2+1)/\ratioscale}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\heightfactor{sqrt(\ratioscale^2+1)}
    \pgf@x=\widthfactor\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=\heightfactor\pgf@y%
    % 
    % Adjust height, if necessary
    % 
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}}%
    \ifdim\pgf@y<.5\pgf@yc%
      \pgf@y=.5\pgf@yc%
    \fi%
    % 
    % Adjust width, if necessary
    % 
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}%
    \ifdim\pgf@x<.5\pgf@xc%
      \pgf@x=.5\pgf@xc%
    \fi%
    % 
    % Add outer sep
    % 
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%  
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@yb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%  
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xb%
    \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yb%
  }

  \inheritanchor[from=ellipse]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=ellipse]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=ellipse]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=ellipse]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=ellipse]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=ellipse]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=ellipse]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=ellipse]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=ellipse]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=ellipse]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=ellipse]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=ellipse]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=ellipse]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=ellipse]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=ellipse]{south east}

  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=ellipse]
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={draw},
  every newellipse node/.style={inner sep=0pt}
]
\path node (a) {A} -- ++(2cm,0) 
      node (b) {B};
\node[fit=(a)(b), newellipse] {};
\node[fit=(a)(b), red, newellipse, ellipse ratio=2] {};
\node[fit=(a)(b), blue, newellipse, ellipse ratio=6] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Here's my original, somewhat more pragmatic answer:

You can adjust the `inner xsep` and `inner ysep` of the large ellipse independently, or use `xscale` and `yscale`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={inner sep=1pt},
  proc/.style={shape=ellipse, draw}
]
\path node[proc] (q) {q} -- ++(2cm,0) 
      node[proc] (p1) {p$_1$} -- ++(1.5cm,0)
      node (d) {\ldots} -- ++(1.5cm,0)
      node[proc] (pn) {p$_n$};
\node[fit=(q)(p1)(d)(pn), proc, inner xsep=-3ex,inner ysep=2ex] {};
\node[fit=(q)(p1)(d)(pn), proc, red, xscale=0.75,yscale=2.5] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In your examples, all `--` (the `line to` operators) are unnecessary...

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution with the following macro syntex:

```
\Ellipse(<x_centre>,<y_centre>)(<width>,<height>){<label>}
```

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\def\Ellipse(#1,#2)(#3,#4)#5{\psellipse(#1,#2)(#3,#4)\rput(#1,#2){#5}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(8,2)
  \psellipse(4,1)(4,1)
  \Ellipse(1,1)(0.5,0.3){$p_{1}$}
  \Ellipse(3,1)(0.5,0.3){$p_{2}$}
  \Ellipse(5,1)(0.5,0.3){$\dots$}
  \Ellipse(7,1)(0.5,0.3){$p_{n}$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]