# Ideal shape of elliptical nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24615/painting-an-ellipse-that-fits-a-row-of-node-but-is-not-narrow-and-long) the issue was to manually adjust the aspect ratio of an elliptical node.  I was more interested in finding a way to automate the process based on objective criteria.  I will be showing my own answer, but am interested in other ideas.

Elliptical nodes are larger than rectangular nodes (depending on `inner sep`) and therefore more difficult to pack closely together.

This shows the default TikZ elliptical node.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[ellipse,draw,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {test};
\node[ellipse,draw,inner sep=0pt] at (0,-1) {wide test};
\node[ellipse,draw,inner sep=0pt] at (0,-2) {a very very wide test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: default]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Latex math]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newlength{\tempw}
\newlength{\temph}
\newcommand{\minarea}[2][\empty]{% #1 = draw keywords (optional), #2 = node name
  \pgfextractx{\tempw}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{east}}}%
  \pgfextracty{\temph}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{south}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{north}}}%
  \draw[#1] (#2) ellipse[x radius={0.707\tempw},y radius={0.707\temph}];
}
\newcommand{\mintotal}[2][\empty]{% #1 = draw keywords (optionsl), #2 = node name
  \pgfextractx{\tempw}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{east}}}%
  \pgfextracty{\temph}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{south}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{north}}}%
  \pgfmathparse{atan(pow(\temph/\tempw,1/3))}%
  \let\tempt=\pgfmathresult
  \draw[#1] (#2) ellipse[x radius={0.5\tempw/cos(\tempt)},y radius={0.5\temph/sin(\tempt)}];
}
\newcommand{\minmax}[2][\empty]{% #1 = draw keywords (optionsl), #2 = node name
  \pgfextractx{\tempw}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{east}}}%
  \pgfextracty{\temph}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{south}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{north}}}%
  \pgfmathparse{\temph/\tempw}%
  \let\aspect=\pgfmathresult
  \def\tempt{45.0}%
  \foreach \i in {1,2,3} {%
    \pgfmathparse{0.5*(sin(\tempt) - \aspect*cos(\tempt)) + (\aspect-1)*sin(2*\tempt)}%
    \let\a=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{-cos(\tempt) - \aspect*sin(\tempt) - (\aspect-1)*cos(2*\tempt)}%
    \let\b=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{-sin(\tempt) + \aspect*cos(\tempt) - 0.5*(\aspect-1)*sin(2*\tempt)}%
    \let\c=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{\b*\b - 4*\a*\c}%
    \let\d=\pgfmathresult
    \ifdim \d pt<0pt\relax \pgfmathparse{-\c/\b}%
    \else
      \ifdim \b pt<0pt\relax \pgfmathparse{0.5*(-\b-sqrt(\d))/\a}%
      \else \pgfmathparse{0.5*(-\b+sqrt(\d))/\a}%
      \fi
    \fi
    \let\e=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{\tempt + deg(\e)}%
    \global\let\tempt=\pgfmathresult
  }%
  \draw[#1] (#2) ellipse[x radius={0.5\tempw/cos(\tempt)},y radius={0.5\temph/sin(\tempt)}];
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=yellow,inner sep=0pt] (A) at (0,0) {test};
\minarea{A}\mintotal[red]{A}\minmax[green]{A}
\node[fill=yellow,inner sep=0pt] (B) at (0,-1) {wide test};
\minarea{B}\mintotal[red]{B}\minmax[green]{B}
\node[fill=yellow,inner sep=0pt] (C) at (0,-2) {a very very wide test};
\minarea{C}\mintotal[red]{C}\minmax[green]{C}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 3):

John Kormylo's answer is astonishing, but isn't an `inner xsep=0pt` (please note the **x**sep) enough?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[ellipse,draw,inner xsep=0pt] at (0,0) {test};
    \node[ellipse,draw,inner xsep=0pt] at (0,-1) {wide test};
    \node[ellipse,draw,inner xsep=0pt] at (0,-2) {a very very wide test};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect all this really does is make the rectangle taller (relative to inner sep=0pt).

Comment: @JohnKormylo I suspect I didn't understand the question...