# My tikz-cd diagram doesn't fit in the text area

Tags: tikz-cd

How do I make my graph fit in the text area? This is an example graph - I have other graphs which which I have a similar problem, so I am hoping for a general solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
         \begin{tikzcd}[
            cells={nodes={draw=black, ellipse, anchor=center, minimum height=\nodeheight}}]
            new\ Channel(low) \arrow[Rightarrow, dd, PineGreen, bend right=50] &
                new\ Channel(low) \arrow[Rightarrow, dd, PineGreen] &
                new\ Channel(low) \arrow[Rightarrow, dd, PineGreen, bend right=50]\\
            |[fill=darkgray,text=yellow]|low \arrow[rightarrow, d, violet] &
                & |[fill=darkgray,text=yellow]|low \arrow[rightarrow, d, violet]\\
            inLow1 \arrow[Rightarrow, d, PineGreen] &
                outLow \arrow[rightarrow, d, violet] &
                inLow2 \arrow[Rightarrow, d, PineGreen]\\
            read(inLow1) \arrow[Rightarrow, d, PineGreen] &
                |[fill=darkgray,text=yellow]|low &
                read(inLow2) \arrow[Rightarrow, d, PineGreen]\\
            a.f \arrow[Leftrightarrow, r, WildStrawberry] &
                c.f \arrow[rightarrow, u, violet] &
                b.f \arrow[Leftrightarrow, l, WildStrawberry]\\
            a \arrow[Rightarrow, r, PineGreen] &
                c \arrow[violet]{u}[description]{\text{inference rule}} &
                b \arrow[Rightarrow, l, PineGreen]\\
            new\ Foo \arrow[Rightarrow, u, PineGreen] &
                read(inHigh) \arrow[rightarrow, u, violet] &
                new\ Foo \arrow[Rightarrow, u, PineGreen]\\
            & inHigh \arrow[Rightarrow, u, PineGreen] &\\
            & |[fill=darkgray,text=yellow]|high \arrow[rightarrow, u, violet] &\\
            & new\ Channel(high) \arrow[Rightarrow, uu, PineGreen, bend right=50]                                                                                               
        \end{tikzcd}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a general solution for the “elephant in a suitcase” problem? Please, make the example compilable, it isn't as it stands. Also make sure that the text width is set to the one you're using in your full document.

Comment: tikzcd is probably not the best tool to make process diagrams like this.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399116/ideal-shape-of-elliptical-nodes?r=SearchResults&s=1|58.8118

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no “general solution”: if your suitcase is big, you can squeeze an elephant in it; if it's small, you can't and you need to reduce the elephant's size.

This version fits in the standard text width of `article`.

I added a definition for `\nodeheight`, it doesn't seem to influence the width.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\usepackage{showframe} % just to see the margins

\def\nodeheight{24pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering\footnotesize
         \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,
            cells={nodes={draw=black, ellipse, anchor=center, minimum height=\nodeheight}}]
            \text{new Channel(low)} \arrow[Rightarrow, dd, PineGreen, bend right=50] &
                \text{new Channel(low)} \arrow[Rightarrow, dd, PineGreen] &
                \text{new Channel(low)} \arrow[Rightarrow, dd, PineGreen, bend right=50]\\
            |[fill=darkgray,text=yellow]|\text{low} \arrow[rightarrow, d, violet] &
                & |[fill=darkgray,text=yellow]|\text{low} \arrow[rightarrow, d, violet]\\
            \text{inLow1} \arrow[Rightarrow, d, PineGreen] &
                \text{outLow} \arrow[rightarrow, d, violet] &
                \text{inLow2} \arrow[Rightarrow, d, PineGreen]\\
            \text{read(inLow1)} \arrow[Rightarrow, d, PineGreen] &
                |[fill=darkgray,text=yellow]|\text{low} &
                \text{read(inLow2)} \arrow[Rightarrow, d, PineGreen]\\
            \text{a.f} \arrow[Leftrightarrow, r, WildStrawberry] &
                \text{c.f} \arrow[rightarrow, u, violet] &
                \text{b.f} \arrow[Leftrightarrow, l, WildStrawberry]\\
            \text{a} \arrow[Rightarrow, r, PineGreen] &
                \text{c} \arrow[violet]{u}[description]{\text{inference rule}} &
                \text{b} \arrow[Rightarrow, l, PineGreen]\\
            \text{new Foo} \arrow[Rightarrow, u, PineGreen] &
                \text{read(inHigh)} \arrow[rightarrow, u, violet] &
                \text{new\ Foo} \arrow[Rightarrow, u, PineGreen]\\
            & \text{inHigh} \arrow[Rightarrow, u, PineGreen] &\\
            & |[fill=darkgray,text=yellow]|\text{high} \arrow[rightarrow, u, violet] &\\
            & \text{new Channel(high)} \arrow[Rightarrow, uu, PineGreen, bend right=50]                                                                                               
        \end{tikzcd}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `showframe` package is used just to show that the diagram fits.

You should be using `\text` for the labels, and already this saves a lot of space.

[image]

Comment: +1 for elephant story :-). Of course, solution is nice.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't end up wrapping the labels in `\text` as the current formatting was important. However, using `\footnotesize` and `column sep=small` made the difference!

Comment: @DavidPoxon The formatting without text uses math italic and is wrong to begin with. Use `\textit` if you want italics.

Comment: @egreg okay, will do. Thank you!