# Is it possible to use tikzpicture environment just for measurements and actually not create a picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create "complex" picture which contains ellipse node.
To draw the "complex" picture, I need dimensions of that ellipse node **before** I draw it.
Unfortunately, since the node shape is ellipse, I can't calculate its dimensions by just measuring dimensions of the text in it.

Therefore, I would like to:

1. Create **fake** tikz picture with just that ellipse node.
2. Set global variables with correct dimensions of ellipse node while in **fake** picture environment.
3. Drop the **fake** picture(Do not generate it anyhow, anywhere).
4. Create "complex" picture by using the global variables with dimensions of ellipse node.

Also, it is highly preferable to be able to use calculations with **fake** tikz picture in preamble.

General idea(not compilable):

```
\documentclass {article}
\RequirePackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\RequirePackage {xparse}
\RequirePackage {tikz}

\usetikzlibrary {shapes}

\ExplSyntaxOn

    \dim_new:N \l_x_west
    \dim_new:N \l_x_east

    \dim_new:N \g_ellipse_width

    % Fake picture which will not be generated, just used for calculation of ellipse width.
    \begin {FAKE tikzpicture}

        \node (ellipse) [ellipse, fill = blue] { Some~text.};

        \pgfextractx {\l_x_west} {\pgfpointanchor {ellipse} {west}}
        \pgfextractx {\l_x_east} {\pgfpointanchor {ellipse} {east}}
        \dim_gset:Nn \g_ellipse_width {\l_x_east - \l_x_west}

    \end {FAKE tikzpicture}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin {document}

    \begin {tikzpicture}
        % Draw complex picture using the \g_ellipse_width
    \end {tikzpicture}

\end {document}
```

Is there any method to achieve this **fake** tikz picture environment?

Comment: Yes, you can use e.g. a `\savebox` to measure things. Note, however, that in most real life situations this is not necessary.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newsavebox\sandbox
\begin{document}
\savebox\sandbox{\tikz{\node[ellipse]{hello world};}}
the ellipse is \the\wd\sandbox\space wide and \the\ht\sandbox\space high.
\end{document}`

Comment: @marmot, as always, fast with all the answers that I need! Thank you, again :D Please make it official answer so I can accept it.

Comment: As long as your problem is solved, from my perspective everything is fine. I am retiring from this site, in which rogue users can do as much harm as they want.

Comment: It is, thank you! I am very sorry to hear that, I hope you change your mind...

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399116/ideal-shape-of-elliptical-nodes?r=SearchResults&s=1|99.1012

Comment: @JohnKormylo, thanks, but unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem. I ended up with new issue regarding this approach: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502643/how-to-properly-use-savebox-with-tikz-externalize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/user121799) answered in the comment, here is the solution using the `savebox` to save picture's dimensions without drawing it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newsavebox\sandbox

\begin{document}

    \savebox\sandbox
    {
        \tikz
        {
            \node[ellipse]{hello world};
        }
    }

    the ellipse is \the\wd\sandbox\space wide and \the\ht\sandbox\space high.
\end{document}
```

For a case when `\tikzexternalize` is used, see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502643/how-to-properly-use-savebox-with-tikz-externalize) question.