# How to properly use savebox with tikz externalize?

Tags: tikz-pgf, latex3, tikz-external, bounding-box

I am unable to properly capture dimensions with `savebox` while `tikzexternalize` is on.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass {article}

\RequirePackage {tikz}
\RequirePackage {expl3}

\usetikzlibrary {shapes}
\usetikzlibrary {external}

% Make every {tikzpicture} block as separate *.png image.
\tikzexternalize [prefix = tests/]
\tikzsetfigurename {test_}
\tikzset{export as png/.style={external/system call/.add = {}{; convert -density 300 -resize 800x600 "\image.pdf" "\image.png"}}}
\tikzset{export as png}

\ExplSyntaxOn

    \tikzset{external/export~next = false} % This is needed for savebox to work.

    \newsavebox \sandbox
    \savebox \sandbox
    {
        \begin {tikzpicture}
            \node [ellipse, minimum~size = 10pt] { };
        \end {tikzpicture}
    }

    \dim_const:Nn \c_ellipse_width {\the\wd\sandbox\space}
    \dim_const:Nn \c_something {16pt}

\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin {document}

    \ExplSyntaxOn

        \dim_log:N \c_ellipse_width
        \dim_log:N \c_something

        \begin {tikzpicture}

            \dim_log:N \c_ellipse_width
            \dim_log:N \c_something
            \node [ellipse, align = center] {\the\c_ellipse_width \\ \the\c_something};

        \end {tikzpicture}

    \ExplSyntaxOff

\end {document}
```

When compiled like this, the main *.log will show correct values:
`> \c_ellipse_width=10.0pt.`
`> \c_something=16.0pt.`

While the tests/test_0.log will change the width and show:
`> \c_ellipse_width=405.83112pt.`
`> \c_something=16.0pt.`

Needless to say, the picture `tests/test_0.png` will draw incorrect values.

When parts of code regarding `tikzexternalize` are commented-out, the main *.log shows:
`> \c_ellipse_width=10.0pt.`
`> \c_something=16.0pt.`

The *.pdf content has correct values drawn in this scenario.

How can I correctly measure dimensions of `tikzpicture` while `tikzexternalize` is on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem is related to tikz optimizations.
To avoid this issue, just disable optimizations with `\tikzset{external/optimize = false}`.

Solution:

```
\documentclass {article}

\RequirePackage {tikz}
\RequirePackage {expl3}

\usetikzlibrary {shapes}
\usetikzlibrary {external}

% Make every {tikzpicture} block as separate *.png image.
\tikzexternalize [prefix = tests/]
\tikzsetfigurename {test_}
\tikzset{export as png/.style={external/system call/.add = {}{; convert -density 300 -resize 800x600 "\image.pdf" "\image.png"}}}
\tikzset{export as png}
\tikzset{external/optimize = false} % <--------------------------------

\ExplSyntaxOn

    \tikzset{external/export~next = false} % This is needed for savebox to work.

    \newsavebox \sandbox
    \savebox \sandbox
    {
        \begin {tikzpicture}
            \node [ellipse, minimum~size = 10pt] { };
        \end {tikzpicture}
    }

    \dim_const:Nn \c_ellipse_width {\the\wd\sandbox\space}
    \dim_const:Nn \c_something {16pt}

\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin {document}

    \ExplSyntaxOn

        \dim_log:N \c_ellipse_width
        \dim_log:N \c_something

        \begin {tikzpicture}

            \dim_log:N \c_ellipse_width
            \dim_log:N \c_something
            \node [ellipse, align = center] {\the\c_ellipse_width \\ \the\c_something};

        \end {tikzpicture}

    \ExplSyntaxOff

\end {document}
```