# How do I make a custom node using the height of the bounding box?

Tags: box

I've been playing around with custom arcs, but I can't seem to figure out how to set the arc radius automatically. Goal is to create a node that bounds two semi-circles and gets wider as needed

Links to the desired image at at the end

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4qag.jpg

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mynode}{%
O{}
m
m
m
O{}
}{
{
\node [#1] (#2)  at #3 {#4};

\def\ra{.3cm}

\draw  [#5]  (#2.north west) arc
    [
        start angle=90,
        end angle=270,
        x radius=\ra,
        y radius=\ra
    ] ;
    

\draw [#5] (#2.north east)to [in=0,out=180] (#2.north west);
\draw [#5] (#2.south east)to [in=0,out=180] (#2.south west);

\draw  [#5]  (#2.south east) arc
    [
        start angle=270,
        end angle=450,
        x radius=\ra,
        y radius=\ra
    ] ;

 
}
}


[![This is what I want to make][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4qag.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuZgn.jpg
```

Comment: The linked image uses circular arcs: x radius = y radius.  It is basically a rectangle with rounded corners.  OTOH, if you want elliptical nodes, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399116/ideal-shape-of-elliptical-nodes?r=SearchResults&s=1|54.4383

Comment: Thank you. I really want the circular arcs. Just can’t use a macro to calculate their radii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `\pgfextracty` etc. to get the height of the node.  I also combined all your draws into one path.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newlength{\mydiameter}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mynode}{% #1 = node options (optional), #2 = node name, #3 = coordinates, #4 = text, #5 = draw options (optional)
O{}
m
m
m
O{}
}{%
{%
\node [#1] (#2)  at #3 {#4};

\pgfextracty{\mydiameter}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{south}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{north}}}%

\draw  [#5]  (#2.north west) arc
    [
        start angle=90,
        end angle=270,
        radius={0.5\mydiameter}
    ] -- (#2.south east) arc
    [
        start angle=-90,
        end angle=90,
        radius={0.5\mydiameter}
    ] -- cycle;
}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\mynode{A}{(0,0)}{Test}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: wow perfect! thank you. good clean example.