# Why is the text not centered inside the ellipse?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Why is the text not centered inside the ellipse?

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by pascal974, removing `text width=4.3em` works fine but this would cause the ellipse width too big. How can I solve that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shadows.blur, arrows.meta, shapes}


\tikzset{
  shadow/.style={%
    preaction={%
      fill=black!20, transform canvas={xshift=2.5pt, yshift=-1.5pt}
    }
  }
}

\tikzstyle{ellip}=[draw,draw=none,ellipse,fill=red!20,text width=4.3em,text badly centered,minimum height=4em]  

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]  

    \node[ellip,shadow]  (n1)  {Specification};  

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: with text width=4.3em, you limit the width, which causes an overfull of 12 pt. Without it it works fine

Comment: @pascal974 but the ellipse width is too big without setting text width. How would you solve that?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399116/ideal-shape-of-elliptical-nodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a small negative value for `inner sep`:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shadows.blur, arrows.meta, shapes}

\tikzset{
  shadow/.style={%
    preaction={%
      fill=black!20, transform canvas={xshift=2.5pt, yshift=-1.5pt}
    }
  }
}

\tikzstyle{ellip}=[draw,draw=none,ellipse,fill=red!20,inner sep=-1mm,minimum height=4em]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]  
  \node[ellip,shadow] (n1) {Specification};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Nice, I did try `inner sep` and with negative value as well but it didn't wok as I still kept `text width` there. Soon I just found a problem with this as it does work for this but then other ellipses also change as well. Probably I should make different styles for different ellipses.

Comment: It would be nice if I can keep the text width as well. It's like just shift that text to the left a bit.

Comment: @internet, do you want the text width to be always fixed with text wrapping? Or a minimum with, and a single line?

Comment: I prefer text wrapping.

Comment: @internet, provided you make your `text width` larger than your longest word it will ok with `align=center`. Your code in your question doesn't work because *Specification* is longer than 4.3em.

Comment: I tried `text width=5em` with `align=center` but it still doesn't center.

Comment: @internet Make it large enough to avoid the overfull hbox warning. (>= 5.5em for Specification)

Comment: I see. Not know the word is that long. Combining `text width = 6em` with `inner sep` and `align=center` seems to give the best result.

Comment: @internet Isn't that what you already have? `inner sep` is included in your `elipp` style. You can take it out of there and put it in your node properties for each node if you want to adjust it for each node.