# Nested ellipses in tikzpicture: Chomsky hierarchy

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

I'd like to draw the Chomsky hierarchy using `tikz`, similar to:

[image: Chomsky hierarchy]

I have the following so far, for a subset of the hierarchy:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}
% ----------

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{venn} = [ellipse, minimum height=3em, minimum width=12em, draw]
        \node [venn] (cs) at (0, $re.south$) {Context Sensitive};
        \node [venn, minimum height=10em] (re) at (0,0)  {Recursively Enumerable};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I:

1. Anchor all of the shapes to the same point in the centre at the bottom of the diagram?
2. Align the text to the top of each ellipse - is `shift` appropriate here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naively one may think this should be simple with `fit` but unfortunately `ellipse` fits are not tight by default. (See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24621/121799) for a tighter fit, but my naive attempt to use it did not yield the desired results.) So one may do it differently. Note that this is not absolutely fool-proof but can be made so with more efforts. However, for the case at hand it works.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,breathe dist/.initial=2ex]
    \foreach \X [count=\Y,remember=\Y as \LastY] in 
    {regular,context free,context sensitive,recursively enumerable}
     {\ifnum\Y=1
      \node[ellipse,draw,outer sep=0pt] (F-\Y) {\X};
     \else
      \node[anchor=south] (T-\Y) at (F-\LastY.north) {\X};
      \path let \p1=($([yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/breathe dist}]T-\Y.north)-(F-\LastY.south)$),
      \p2=($(F-1.east)-(F-1.west)$),\p3=($(F-1.north)-(F-1.south)$)
      in ($([yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/breathe dist}]T-\Y.north)!0.5!(F-\LastY.south)$) 
      node[minimum height=\y1,minimum width={\y1*\x2/\y3},
      draw,ellipse,inner sep=0pt] (F-\Y){};
     \fi}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And a version for Minhthien_2016:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,breathe dist/.initial=4ex]
    \foreach \X [count=\Y,remember=\Y as \LastY] in 
    {regular,context free,context sensitive,recursively enumerable}
     {\ifnum\Y=1
      \node[ellipse,draw,outer sep=0pt] (F-\Y) {\X};
     \else 
      \path[decoration={text along path,
        text={|\sffamily|\X},text align=center,raise=0.3ex},decorate] 
        let \p1=($(F-\LastY.north)-(F-\LastY.west)$)
       in (F-\LastY.west) arc(180:0:\x1 and \y1);
      \path let \p1=($([yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/breathe dist}]F-\LastY.north)
      -(F-\LastY.south)$),
      \p2=($(F-1.east)-(F-1.west)$),\p3=($(F-1.north)-(F-1.south)$)
      in ($([yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/breathe dist}]F-\LastY.north)!0.5!(F-\LastY.south)$) 
      node[minimum height=\y1,minimum width={\y1*\x2/\y3},
      draw,ellipse,inner sep=0pt] (F-\Y){};
     \fi}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I format texs are also ellipses?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Sorry, I do not understand this question.

Comment: It looks like word art in Word.

Comment: I like the flexibility of this solution, and there's a bit more room for the text to breathe - thanks!

Comment: @AdamWilliams Sure. I added a key `,breathe dist`, which is initially set  to `2ex`. You can control the "breathing distance" by adjusting that key. (I also added another version for fun, where the key of the same name has a related meaning.)

Comment: Hi, I want a similar diagram, but I am unable to decipher your code. Can you specifically tell me how to add labels to an ellipse which lie along the curve as in the second diagram? I am sorry, I am unable to decipher the code.

Comment: @EkanshdeepGupta What precisely do you mean by that? The label texts are in the list `{regular,context free,context sensitive,recursively enumerable}`, separated by commas. If you change these texts you will get a different output. Or are you talking about different labels?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Given an ellipse, I want to add a label such that its letters go along the curve of the ellipse. 

For instance, in the first figure, the labels ```context free```, ```context sensitive``` etc are straight rectangular blocks of text. In the second figure however, they are curved and follow the curvature of the ellipses.

I want the behavior of the second figure.

Comment: @EkanshdeepGupta But you could just copy the code of the second example and modify the texts. Or do you want to generalize the code in some way?

Comment: Yes, I want a few things inside my ellipses and so on, I want a completely different figure. I just want to know how you got the curved labels. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EkanshdeepGupta The relevant command is `\path[decoration={text along path,
        text={<text>},text align=center,raise=0.3ex},decorate] <path>;` These things are described in detail in section **50.6 Text Decorations** of pgfmanual v1.3.1.

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a perfect solution, but it fits this particular case: write words above another node.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[above,ellipse,minimum height=2em,minimum width=4em,draw] (a) {regular};
\node[above,ellipse,minimum height=4em,minimum width=8em,draw] (b) {};
\node[above,ellipse,minimum height=6em,minimum width=12em,draw] (c) {};
\node[above,ellipse,minimum height=8em,minimum width=16em,draw] (d) {};
\path (a.north) node[above] {context-free}
    (b.north) node[above] {context-sensitive}
    (c.north) node[above] {recursively enumerable};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]