# Drawing a chevron process in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could you please help me drawing this image? Thank you so much!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}%
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\arrowtextfont}{\color{white}}%

\newcommand{\diagram}[1]{%
 % changed from "\x in" to "\x/\clr in"
 \foreach [count=\xi, count=\prevx from 0] \x/\clr in {#1}{%
  \ifnum\xi=1
    % added fill=\clr,signal from=none
    \node[product,fill=\clr,signal from=none] (x-\xi) {\x};
  \else
    % added fill=\clr
    \node[product,fill=\clr,anchor=west] (x-\xi) at (x-\prevx.east) {\x};
  \fi
 }
}
\definecolor{firstarrowcolor}{cmyk}{0.55,0.03,0.13,0}%
\definecolor{secondarrowcolor}{cmyk}{0.70,0.04,0.16,0}%
\definecolor{thirdarrowcolor}{cmyk}{0.85,0.04,0.20,0}%
\definecolor{fourtharrowcolor}{cmyk}{1,0.05,0.23,0}%

\tikzset{product size/.style={minimum width=2cm, 
    minimum height=15pt,
    text height=1ex,
  },
  product/.style={ % removed fill and text colour setting
    draw,signal, 
    signal to=east, 
    signal from=west,
    product size,
    draw=white
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}%
\diagram{\arrowtextfont Test/firstarrowcolor,\arrowtextfont Second
text/secondarrowcolor,\arrowtextfont Third
text/thirdarrowcolor,\arrowtextfont Fourth text/fourtharrowcolor}%
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 8):

A `smartdiagram`-based version:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{uniform sequence color=true,
    sequence item uniform color=cyan!20,
    sequence item border color=white,
}
\smartdiagram[sequence diagram]{Brainstorm,Determine Problem,Compose Hypothesis}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

And the required modification to the style in order for the first item to set `signal from=nowhere`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\tikzset{sequence item/.append style={
  /utils/exec={\ifnum\xi=1% modifying the style of only one node - from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/502947
    \tikzset{signal from=nowhere}
    \fi
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{uniform sequence color=true,
    sequence item uniform color=cyan!20,
    sequence item border color=white,
}
\smartdiagram[sequence diagram]{Brainstorm,Determine Problem,Compose Hypothesis}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Nice trick. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `signal` node shape and put the nodes on a chain.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.symbols}
\definecolor{myc}{RGB}{224,237,243}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={shape=signal,signal from=west, signal to=east,
    align=center,fill=myc,font=\sffamily,on chain,minimum height=3.5em,
    inner xsep=1em},start chain=going right,node distance=1ex]
 \path node[signal from=nowhere]{Brainstorm}     node{Determine\\ Problem} 
    node{Compose\\ Hypothesis};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]