# Document header with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, box

Until now I had been using drawio to do the header's of some of my documents. I would like to shift to tikz, could anyone help me to do so ?

[image]

[image]

Below what I have done. It's not perfect but it's a start. Help would be appreciated:

1. for positioning nodes in relation to each other;
2. to put several texts in different places in the same node;
3. for the shape of the arrow, I would like one with an inside angle at the back.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{9,72,90}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{124,184,201}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [rectangle,draw=darkblue,fill=darkblue,thick,rounded corners,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=13cm,text=white] (titre) {\large{La photographie numérique}};
    \node [rectangle,draw=darkblue,fill=darkblue,thick,rounded corners,minimum height=3cm, text width=5cm, text=white] (competences) [right=of titre] {Identifier les étapes de la construction de l'image finale};
    \node[single arrow, draw=darkblue,fill=lightblue, single arrow head extend=0cm,text=white] (un) [below=of titre] {Construction de l'image};
    \node[single arrow, draw=darkblue,fill=lightblue, single arrow head extend=0cm,text=white]
(deux) [right=of un] {Métadonnées EXIF};
\node[single arrow, draw=darkblue,fill=lightblue, single arrow head extend=0cm,text=white]
(trois) [right=of deux] {...};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

It's almost done !
I need some help to align the arrows on the left and the two nodes by the top.
Thanks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{9,72,90}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{124,184,201}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2pt,
    start chain = going right,
    start/.style = {signal, 
                    draw=darkblue, 
                    fill=lightblue,
                    text width=2cm, 
                    minimum height=1cm, 
                    font=\scriptsize,
                    text=white,
                    signal pointer angle=120, on chain},
    cont/.style = {start, 
                    signal from=west}
    ]
    
    \node[start](a) {\bfseries Construction de l'image};
    \node[above=2pt of a, 
            rectangle, 
            draw=darkblue, 
            fill=darkblue,
            minimum height=2cm,
            minimum width=13cm,
            text=white,
            inner sep=1pt]
            (titre){\large{La photographie numérique}};
    \node[cont] {\bfseries Métadonnées EXIF};
    \node[cont](b) {\bfseries Step3};
    \node[right=2pt of titre,
            rectangle,
            draw=darkblue,
            fill=darkblue,thick,
            rounded corners,
            minimum height=3cm,
            text width=5cm,
            text=white]
            (competences){Identifier les étapes de la construction de l'image finale};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Final solution. Thanks to JS Bibra and his use of anchor

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{9,72,90}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{124,184,201}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2pt,
    start chain = going right,
    start/.style = {signal, 
                    draw=darkblue,
                    very thick, 
                    fill=lightblue,
                    text width=2cm, 
                    minimum height=1cm, 
                    font=\scriptsize,
                    text=white,
                    signal pointer angle=120, on chain},
    cont/.style = {start, 
                    signal from=west}
    ]
    
    \node[start,](a) {\bfseries Construction de l'image};
    \node[above=0.6cm of a.west,
            anchor=south west,
            rectangle,
            rounded corners,
            draw=darkblue, 
            fill=darkblue,
            minimum height=2cm,
            minimum width=13cm,
            text=white,
            inner sep=1pt]
            (boitetitre){};
    \node [right=1em of boitetitre.west,
        anchor=south west,
        text=white]     
        (titre) {\Large{La photographie numérique}};
    \node [left=1em of boitetitre.south east,
        anchor=south east,
        text=white]     
        (titre) {\Large{Troisième}};
    \node [right=1em of boitetitre.west,
        anchor=south west,
        text=white]     
        (titre) {\Large{La photographie numérique}};
    \node[cont] {\bfseries Métadonnées EXIF};
    \node[cont](b) {\bfseries Step3};
    \node[right=5.4cm of boitetitre.north east, anchor=north east,
            rectangle,
            draw=darkblue,
            fill=darkblue,thick,
            rounded corners,
            minimum height=3cm,
            text width=5cm,
            text=white]
            (competences){Identifier les étapes de la construction de l'image finale};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This should be simple with the TikZ nodes and its various shapes. There are many such examples in the documentation.

Comment: You can take a look to the `smartdiagram` package (`sequence diagram`) or, directly related to the question, there's an old question (that incidentally is the origin of the `sequence diagram`): [Drawing a chevron process in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/525818/13304)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554063/197451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{9,72,90}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{124,184,201}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2pt,
    start chain = going right,
    start/.style = {signal, 
                    draw=darkblue, 
                    fill=lightblue,
                    text width=2cm, 
                    minimum height=1cm, 
                    font=\scriptsize,
                    text=white,
                    signal pointer angle=120, on chain},
    cont/.style = {start, 
                    signal from=west}
    ]
    
    \node[start,](a) {\bfseries Construction de l'image};
    \node[above=0.6cm of a.west, anchor=south west,
            rectangle, 
            draw=darkblue, 
            fill=darkblue,
            minimum height=2cm,
            minimum width=13cm,
            text=white,
            inner sep=1pt]
            (titre){\large{La photographie numérique}};
    \node[cont] {\bfseries Métadonnées EXIF};
    \node[cont](b) {\bfseries Step3};
    \node[right=5.4cm of titre.north east, anchor=north east,
            rectangle,
            draw=darkblue,
            fill=darkblue,thick,
            rounded corners,
            minimum height=3cm,
            text width=5cm,
            text=white]
            (competences){Identifier les étapes de la construction de l'image finale};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```